# Greater than a multiplied value in an SSRS expression

Tags: ssrs-2008

Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do through an expression.

if `response_time > response goal`, "colour", but if `response_time > response_goal * 0.25`, "colour#2"

Can this work through an expression?

At the beating my head against the wall stage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refine this expression from Nick somewhat because the first condition would evaluate true even if the second condition is true. It would also be easier to read if you use the Switch function. So try something like this:

```
=Switch(response_time > response_goal and response_time <= response_goal * 0.25,"colour", response_time > response_time * 0.25, "colour#2")
```

UPDATE: Nick was right in order of operations - I was keyed in on the greater than sign and not the math operation. I still prefer the Switch function, but just to correct the record - the expression should look like this:

```
=Switch(response_time > response_goal 0.25 and response_time <= response_goal ,"colour#2", response_time > response_time, "colour")
```

Comment: Since multiplying by 0.25 would lower the number, isn't it possible that the first condition in my example would not be met, but the second condition would? (Example: Response_time = 3 and Response_Goal = 4)

Comment: Yep you're right sorry - was too early in the morning for me apparently to process correctly. My apologies! I've edited my answer. I still think Switch is a better way to deal with multiple conditions rather than nested iifs.

Comment: I actually was unaware of the Switch syntax, so thanks for the demo!

Comment: Outstanding! Thanks very much for the help. It now works exactly how I want it to.. I was pretty close.

Comment: Jason, be sure to make this as the answer so Stacia gets the credit, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely aware of the order of operations that SSRS will use, but try wrapping the multiplied value in parenthesis.

```
IIf(response_time > response_goal, "colour", IIf(response_time > (response_goal * 0.25), "colour#2","default option"))
```

You'd want to change "default option" with whatever the expression should return if `response_time` isn't greater than `response_goal` or `response_goal` * 0.25.